# Draw custom crosshair cursor only draws half of the cursor

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I'm trying to draw a custom crosshair cursor.

This is my function to create the "cross cursor".

**The problem is that it only draw the positive coordinates. 
So I get the half side of the cross.**

[image]

**So the red in this cross isn't visible when I draw it.
A solution would be to make the cross all with positive coordinates but I don't want this.**

Any solutions?

```
private Cursor crossCursor(System.Drawing.Pen pen, int x, int y)
{
    var pic = new Bitmap(x, y);
    var gr = Graphics.FromImage(pic);

    //gr.Clip = new Region(new RectangleF(-x / 2, -y / 2, x, y));

    var pathX = new GraphicsPath();
    var pathY = new GraphicsPath();
    pathY.AddLine(new Point(0, -y), new Point(0, y));
    pathX.AddLine(new Point(-x, 0), new Point(x, 0));
    gr.DrawPath(pen, pathX);
    gr.DrawPath(pen, pathY);

    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    Icon.FromHandle(pic.GetHicon()).Save(stream);

    // Convert saved file into .cur format
    stream.Seek(2, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.WriteByte(2);
    stream.Seek(10, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // Construct Cursor
    return new Cursor(stream);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use positive coords?

Comment: If I work with positive coordinates the problem is the actual hitPoint of my cursor would be the TOP LEFT of the cross and not the middle.

Comment: the hit point has nothing to do with your drawing code, [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11526351/1324033), or [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1674x8.aspx)

Comment: If I draw the cross correct that problem is fixed. Do you have another suggestion fixing my hitPoint problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parameters `x` and `y` are, say, 10 each, you would create a bitmap of 10x10 in your code.

So this line:

```
pathY.AddLine(new Point(0, -y), new Point(0, y));
```

Translates to:

```
pathY.AddLine(new Point(0, -10), new Point(0, 10));
```

The point (0,-10) lies outside of your bitmap and therefore will be invisible.

There's no way you can draw inside the bitmap and show everything if you insist on using negative values...

Comment: Original my code was -y /2 and y / 2 so that would be the same. And that doesn't solves the problem

Comment: If I work with positive coordinates the problem is the actual hitPoint of my cursor would be the TOP LEFT of the cross and not the middle.

Comment: You can change the hotspot of a custom cursor in .NET. See [the accepted answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550918/change-cursor-hotspot-in-winforms-net).