# How do I create a Cursor object from a Bitmap object?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap, cursor

Assuming I have an existing `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object, how do I create a `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor` object with the same pixel data as my `Bitmap` object?

Comment: *You also need to manually use the DesroyIcon() API to release the IntPtr retrieved with GetHicon().

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll give that solution a shot. It's not a duplicate question though, even though the answer is relevant; that question is very situation-specific, whereas this question is general to any situation where you might want to create a Cursor from a Bitmap.

Comment: There's more to a cursor than just a bitmap.  The hotspot and masks are not going to fall from the sky.

Comment: As Hans points out, the "possible duplicate" solution linked to by Romoku is incomplete because it does not show how to set the hotspot. I have posted a better answer below.

Comment: What question is this a "duplicate" of? Just because a question has the same answer as another question, that doesn't mean it's the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550918/change-cursor-hotspot-in-winforms-net). It allows you to both create a Cursor from a Bitmap object and set its hotspot.

```
public struct IconInfo
{
    public bool fIcon;
    public int xHotspot;
    public int yHotspot;
    public IntPtr hbmMask;
    public IntPtr hbmColor;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool GetIconInfo(IntPtr hIcon, ref IconInfo pIconInfo);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateIconIndirect(ref IconInfo icon);

/// <summary>
/// Create a cursor from a bitmap without resizing and with the specified
/// hot spot
/// </summary>
public static Cursor CreateCursorNoResize(Bitmap bmp, int xHotSpot, int yHotSpot)
{
    IntPtr ptr = bmp.GetHicon();
    IconInfo tmp = new IconInfo();
    GetIconInfo(ptr, ref tmp);
    tmp.xHotspot = xHotSpot;
    tmp.yHotspot = yHotSpot;
    tmp.fIcon = false;
    ptr = CreateIconIndirect(ref tmp);
    return new Cursor(ptr);
}


/// <summary>
/// Create a 32x32 cursor from a bitmap, with the hot spot in the middle
/// </summary>
public static Cursor CreateCursor(Bitmap bmp)
{
    int xHotSpot = 16;
    int yHotSpot = 16;

    IntPtr ptr = ((Bitmap)ResizeImage(bmp, 32, 32)).GetHicon();
    IconInfo tmp = new IconInfo();
    GetIconInfo(ptr, ref tmp);
    tmp.xHotspot = xHotSpot;
    tmp.yHotspot = yHotSpot;
    tmp.fIcon = false;
    ptr = CreateIconIndirect(ref tmp);
    return new Cursor(ptr);
}
```

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments, when a `Cursor` is created from an `IntPtr` handle, disposing the cursor will *not* release the handle itself, which will create a memory leak unless you release it yourself manually using the `DestroyIcon` function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);
```

And then you can call the function like this:

```
DestroyIcon(myCursor.Handle);
```

Comment: Cursor created from IntPtr handle does not release the handle when it's disposed. It results in memory leak, unless use manually release Cursor.Handle.

Comment: Good point, thanks for mentioning this!

Comment: It's not a good point, it's a critical point. Can you show an example of how you ended up successfully addressing this memory-leak issue?

Comment: @Jazimov I've edited my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks. I've been working with this and now the problem becomes where exactly to carry out the DestroyIcon operation--do it too soon and the cursor won't show properly...